# where is entity framework 4.3 multiple diagram

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I installed EF 4.3 from NuGet package manager but couldn't see any differences comparing to old version. Mainly I am looking for Multiple Diagrams feature which is mentioned here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

I know it is June 2011 CTP, but the newer version must have it. Another confusing post is this one.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/11/entity-designer-improvements-preview.aspx

Another link I found might be related but I couldn't see satisfactory comments, so I have not tested it.

blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx

This video talks about the features in next version but we are in 2012 and still I can't find the features in v4.3.
channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-812T

Any light on this area is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

None of these features are available in [EF 4.3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx). EF 4.3 is [EF 4.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx) (check what is not in this release paragraph) = DbContext API, code first + bug fixes and improvements + EF Migrations. None of these features target EF designer.

The feature you are looking for was only part of June 2011 CTP and it will be part of .NET 4.5 / VS 11 - it should appear in next developer preview.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tried to search for Entity Framework roadmap for the upcoming releases, but couldn't found it. Any link will be appreciated.

Comment: Here is the best reference you can get: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link Ladislav, now the picture is very much clear. All the new features of EF will be available when the next version of .Net Framework will be released.